# Method doesn't get call in iPhone(simulator), but it works fine on iPhone Retina 4-iPhone5(simulator)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, xcode4.5

In myRootViewController I have `UIPanGesture`, `UIPinchGesture` and `UITapGesture` added to `myScrollView`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   //scroller's pan gesture
    [scroller.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(performScrollViewPanGesture:)];

   //scroller's tap gesture
    tapToEdit = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performTapGesture:)];
    tapToEdit.numberOfTapsRequired = 1.0;
    [scroller addGestureRecognizer:tapToEdit];

    //scroller's pinch gesture
    pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(performPinchGesture:)];
    [scroller addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

}
```

Since I have gestures added to `myScrollView`, it was not calling `ToucehsBegan`, but I also wanted to use `ToucehsBegan` to perform some transformation with `touchesMoved` so I had to make a separate class named `BackgroundTouchLayerController` to call `TouchesBegan` , which is a subclass of `UIScrolView` and I assigned it to `myScrollView`.

In `myScrollView` class `BackgroundTouchLayer` all I am doing is just this.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //start Transformation of my Layers
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //continues Tranforation
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //perform ending Animation
}
```

Now, it does call the `TouchesBegan` to do my transformation always, The problem I am facing is that When I run my application in `iPhone Retina-4 [iPhone 5] (simulator)` and perform `Pan gesture`, it calls my `Pan gesture handler` and does everything right.**BUT** when I run my application in `iPhone [iPhone 4] (simulator)` and perform `Pan Gesture`, it does not calls the `Pan gesture handler` like in `iPhone 5`, instead it calls `TouchesBegan` method from the `myScrollView` class.

Do anyone know, what could have been gone wrong?

I have tried my best to be clear enough, If still something is required please ask me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should definitely provide more code so that we can have an idea about what is happening...

Comment: I have updated my question , Please review it.

Comment: Have you tried to implement - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer from UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and set it as a delegate. Maybe there is somehow a different ordering on the simulator.

Comment: I am not getting it well, can you please add it in answer with some details?

Comment: Did you try enabling the UIScrollViewDelegate and then calling - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView ? 

Does that work on both?

Comment: *my scrollView has a separate class in which I have called TouchesBegan method to perform my tasks.* -- could you please elaborate more on this? what class is it? in which way does your scrollView relate to it (subview, property,..)? provide some code showing this...

Comment: I tried to elaborate it bit more, so any help fellows.

Comment: I tried enabling the 'UIScrollViewDelegate' , but it also never get called in iphone4 (simulator).